# Micronaut - internal and external API

Tags: micronaut

I am looking for a way to have in one microservice an API for public access and another for internal for other private services.

That may be possible with different URLs of course. But looks like swagger/ open api description page is merged.

Public and private API shall have a separate swagger page. People from internet shall not see internal API description. Only the public one.

Any idea?

Comment: You may want to split your microservice into a public- and private service. That will make things easier, also when deploying your app to e.g. k8s. BR

Comment: That is the idea. But how to do this with micronaut?

Comment: I was thinking of splitting your app into two separate Micronaut applications.

Comment: Oh. Then it is a separate service in own docker etc. IMHO too small fragments and making other parts more complicated. I also wondered if 2 ports are possible in one application?

Comment: If you leave out the idea of internal and external apis, is the question really just about how you can generate separate swagger descriptions and specify which endpoints go in each description?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment having two micronaut applications.

So if you work with gradle, just create one gradle project with two submodules
like that:

```
MyAppProject
-> PublicAPIApp (only the public api)
-> MyApp (the public and the private api)
```

You could setup everything together within a simple docker compose file.
And if you hide "MyApp" in a separate docker network which is not accessible from the outside, than you are fine.

If you run your app somewhere in the cloud, the cloud providers also provide something e.g. Azure Api Management (https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/services/api-management/) which does exactly what you want. In that case only one micronaut application is enough, and everything else is done by the api management.

Within micronaut itself (one application nothing more) its not possible to run the application on two ports.
But if you use security (what you realy should), you could use several roles or secure your private api, and leave the public ones unsecured. Swagger and so on, will provide the api anyway, but in most cases that should not be a problem.
If your API user know, what else is possible, but are only allowed if you agree this should be fine.

So as you can see. There is no 'silver bulett'

If you want only one application, use a service or security
If you dont want to use a service or security than you have to use two applications.

Comment: Thank you. I came so far to the same results. Was not successful to generate different swagger in one micronaut app. I don't know yet how to use gradle to generate 2 versions for Kotlin. But it sounds promising. Negative side is of course to have the double amount of instances running (money). With external API like you said regarding Azure (I use AWS but there is the same), I maybe can restrict to a special path of the service like /public/api but the sswagger files for public must be generated separate.

Comment: yeah i think in AWS ist called API Gateway but that also costs money (i work with azure, so i do not know much about amazon)... finally it has two sides. you could run your public api compiled with graal, with runs with a very little footprint, so costs should be not that huge .. on gradle you could also have two independend projects, of you are not familiar with gradle subprojects .. create two container and deploy them ..

Comment: As the architecture grows, splitting the API into a public and private part may no longer be the right decision. Currently, I'm on a GCP project where we had 2 public APIs and several private APIs. To make the public APIs appear as one and keep the auth code in one project, we had to make a separate API-project with Swagger doc that forwarded calls to the the public APIs that now became private. The API Gateway on GCP didn't support OAS 3, hence we had to downgrade the generated OAS 3 to Swagger 2 when creating the def for the GCP API Gateway. BR

Comment: @Roar S. Definitely agree, but I am a big fan of sacrificial architecture and clean code. So if there is no requirement to do so I prefer to start simple